# Highchart and "almost regular" time interval data

Tags: datetime, highcharts

For a Highchart line chart using datetime on the X Axis, how can the chart be initially rendered using data with one `pointInterval`, and dynamically updated using another?

For my case, the initially rendering will utilize exactly 200 samples regardless of the time duration.  For instance, say a given chart's duration is 1 week.  The initial page will receive 200 data points which are 3,024 seconds apart (7*24*60*60/200).  Then, it will be dynamically updated via Ajax every 60 seconds.

I've tried multiple approaches, however, either the Ajax 60 second ticks produce the same change as the initial page 3,024 second ticks or the initially created chart scale is changed or some equally other undesired result.  The chart should primarily remain the same but slowly update with the newly received Ajax data.

The following at https://jsbin.com/zuboyeh/edit?html,output shows several of those attempts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function() {
                /*
                Total of 6 options.

                Using pointAdd or pointUpdate.

                Also, three options this way
                Option 1.  Pre-load w/o time, change pointInterval, then continue with no time.  Doesn't work as it changes past date formats
                Option 2.  Pre-load w/o time, then continue with time.
                Option 3.  Pre-load w/ time, then continue with time.
                */

                //initially page will display daily data for one month
                var numberOfDatapointsToDisplay=200;    //Given
                var chartDuration = 7*24*60*60;  //One week given resulting in 60,4800 seconds
                var secondsInterval = chartDuration/numberOfDatapointsToDisplay;    //3024 seconds
                var pointInterval = 1000*secondsInterval;  //ms
                var tickInterval  = null; //tickInterval is the interval of the tick marks in axis units. Not sure how to handle
                var secondsIntervalAjax=60; //One minute given for ajax request time
                var currentTime=new Date().getTime()/1000; //UTC time
                var secondsStart=currentTime - numberOfDatapointsToDisplay*secondsInterval;   //Start a week in the past and then populate upon page load
                var pointStart = 1000*secondsStart;  //ms

                //Get initial data
                var data1=[],data2=[],data3=[];
                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDatapointsToDisplay; i++) {
                    var v=gv(pointInterval/1000);   //Data simulator for this example
                    data1[i]=v; //attempt using a single value
                    data2[i]=[secondsStart,v];  //attempt using cartesian values
                    secondsStart+=secondsInterval;
                }

                $("#addPoint").click(function() {
                    //Simulate ajax request using addPoint()
                    currentTime+=secondsIntervalAjax;
                    var v=gv(secondsIntervalAjax);
                    chart1.series[0].addPoint(v, true, true); //attempt using a single value
                    chart2.series[0].addPoint([currentTime,v], true, true);  //attempt using cartesian values
                });
                $("#updateSeries").click(function() {
                    //Simulate ajax request using update()
                    currentTime+=secondsIntervalAjax;
                    var v=gv(secondsIntervalAjax);
                    data1.push(v);
                    data2.push([currentTime,v]);
                    chart1.series[0].update({data: data1}); //attempt using a single value
                    chart2.series[0].update({data: data2});  //attempt using cartesian values
                });

                $("#changePointInterval").click(function() {
                    //Try changing the pointInterval used for the initial page data and ajax data
                    chart1.series[0].update({pointInterval: secondsIntervalAjax*1000});
                    chart2.series[0].update({pointInterval: secondsIntervalAjax*1000});
                })

                var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: "line",
                        renderTo: 'container1'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: "datetime",
                        //tickInterval: tickInterval,
                        //tickPixelInterval: 50
                    },
                    series: [
                        {name: 'SeriesName', data: data1},
                    ],
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            pointStart: pointStart,
                            pointInterval: pointInterval,
                        }
                    },
                });
                var chart2 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: "line",
                        renderTo: 'container2'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: "datetime",
                        //tickInterval: tickInterval,
                        dateTimeLabelFormats: {month: '%e. %b',year: '%b'},
                        tickPixelInterval: 50
                    },
                    series: [
                        {name: 'SeriesName', data: data2},
                    ],
                    plotOptions: {
                        spline: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                });

                function gv(s) {
                    //Data simulator for new value after s seconds
                    if ( typeof this.v == 'undefined' ) {
                        this.v = 100;
                    }
                    this.v=this.v+50*numberOfDatapointsToDisplay*(Math.random()-.5) * s/chartDuration;
                    return this.v;
                }


            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="addPoint">addPoint</button>
        <button id="updateSeries">updateSeries</button>
        <button id="changePointInterval">changePointInterval</button>
        <div id="container1" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        <div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how do you want your chart to behave exactly. Initially you have 200 points and `pointInterval` is 3024s (all is fine by far). Then you want to add another point which x position should be last's point x + 60 seconds (`pointInterval` should become smaller from this point)?

Comment: @KamilKulig, yes, `pointInterval` is now 60,000 ms, but changing will effect the previous chart data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each series can have only one `pointInterval` defined.

There're 2 easiest solutions for this problem on the top of my head:

**1. Add another linked series for new values**
`linkedTo:previous` will cause that legend switch will work for both series. Change the colour of the second series so that it looks exactly the same as the first one. Set `pointStart` using the last value from the base series:

```
  events: {
    load: function() {
      var points = this.series[0].points,
        lastPoint = points[points.length - 1];

      this.series[1].update({
        pointStart: lastPoint.x,
        color: this.series[0].color
      });
    }
  }

(...)

series: [{
  name: 'SeriesName',
  data: data1
}, {
  name: 'SeriesName', // same name as the previous series
  pointInterval: secondsIntervalAjax * 10000, // 10 times bigger to see results faster
  linkedTo: ':previous',
  marker: {
    enabled: false
  }
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/gtsw8t3q/

**2. Compute and explicitly assign x value to every point**

No `pointInterval` and `pointStart` required in this case.

Comment: Thanks Kamil,  I suspected each series could only have one pointInterval, but wasn't positive.  knew about your second solution explicitly assigning an x value, but wanted to explore other solutions first.  Thank you for your first solution.